# how to remove android library from within project and place it in Github

Tags: android, android-library

I have an `Android project` in which I have added `Android library` as a module and use it within the project. `Android library` module is part of the project.

what I want to do is, remove the `Android library` from the project and host it in Github and use the `Android library` as a dependency in `Android project`.

Is that possible, if so how can I achieve that please.

If you think I should not be creating a `Android library` within the `Android project` I want to use it in, and create `Android library` as a separate project do let me know as well. (But this was it is a bit hard to debug I think)

Your suggestion and advice will be very helpful

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your Library to [Github Packages](https://help.github.com/en/packages/publishing-and-managing-packages/about-github-packages) in order to use it as a dependency.

Follow this [tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/publishing-android-libraries-to-the-github-package-registry-part-1-7997be54ea5a) to do it.

**Update 1**

Another way to do that is by using [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/docs/). You just need to publish your library into Github repository and then you create a dependency using JitPack from that repo.

Comment: hi thanks for getting back. so I have have my `Android library` within the  `Android project` for now and later when I want to publish it to github, I can just push the Android library to github without including the project right?